# Rails Mysql Find Joined Table's Joined Table By Date Created At Not Within n Months

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am having a hard time with a query. This is in rails (2.1), but maybe I need a find_by_sql.

I have a companies table which has many clients, which have many groups. I need to find companies which have not had any clients with any groups within a certain amount of time (say 3 months).

The best I have come up with is this:

```
Company.all(:include => { :clients => :groups },
:conditions => ["(SELECT count(*) FROM groups WHERE
groups.client_id = clients.id AND clients.company_id = companies.id
AND groups.created_at > ?) = 0 AND companies.is_active = 1 AND
clients.is_active = 1", 3.months.ago])
```

Ideally this would also return the time of the last group made for each company (no idea where to start for that). For this I've been using a separate query for each company:

```
Group.last(:include => { :client => :company },
:conditions => { "companies.id" => company.id })
```

When I run the report, I am getting companies that have groups created in the last month or so, so it doesn't look like my initial query is correct. But I don't know where to go from here.

EDIT:
Here are the table create statements for the tables. I did remove most of the fields and left what is relevant. I hope this works.

```
mysql> show create table companies;
| Table     | Create Table | | companies | CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1646 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table clients;
| Table   | Create Table | clients | CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `CompanyID` (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3374 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table groups;
| Table  | Create Table | groups | CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ClientID` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=157006 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try a real query without subselects?

```
SELECT companies.* FROM companies
 JOIN clients ON clients.company_id = companies.id 
 JOIN groups ON groups.client_id = clients.id
 GROUP BY companies.id
 HAVING MAX(groups.created_at) < '2012-06-01';
```

Comment: ACtually, I am not sure how I didn't try this but it seems to work (except you need to change the group by to companies.id, and MAX must be in a HAVING instead of WHERE.)

Comment: Sorry, I had not a SQL console to try the query.... edited. Thanks for the corrections, +1

Answer (score 0):

If you use your current logic you are forced to use NOT IN () by selecting company IDs of all companies with groups that were created within last 3 months, and then using NOT IN () to select companies with IDs that are not in that list. Note that you don't need count(*) at all since records with 0 count are not going to be there anyway. NOT IN () queries are generally bad idea since they will do a full table scan. Maybe it's better to select a MAX(groups.created_at) and filter ones with MAX(groups.created_at) < 3.months.ago

```
select c.* from companies c 
inner join clients cl on cl.company_id = c.id 
inner join (select g.client_id from groups g group by g.client_id 
having max(g.created_at) < '2012-06-01') t on t.client_id = cl.id;
```

This one should work, and should be a bit faster. Or something like this:

```
select c.* from companies c 
inner join clients cl on cl.company_id = c.id 
where cl.id not in (select distinct g.client_id from groups g 
where g.created_at > '2012-06-01');
```

Not sure which one will perform better against real data.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer; however, the query is extremely slow (took a few minutes to run) and doesn't seem to exclude companies with groups after the given date. I didn't know about MAX though, so I am hoping this will push me to find the answer. If you have any more ideas, I'd be happy to hear them. Thanks!

Comment: can you paste your table create statements for these 3 tables.

Comment: I added the table create statements to the question - I hope it's okay that I had to remove most of the fields. I left what is hopefully most relevant.

Comment: I think there was a slight error in the code you had, which I didn't catch right away. I changed it to this:

`find_by_sql "SELECT co.* FROM companies co WHERE co.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT co.id FROM companies co
        INNER JOIN clients c on c.company_id = co.id
        INNER JOIN groups g ON g.client_id = c.id
        GROUP BY co.id HAVING MAX(g.created_at) < '#{n.to_i.months.ago.to_date}')"`

And it seems to work. It's still very slow (because it's hitting a lot of records I would imagine), but I perhaps I can make the query between a closer date and the end date. Thanks!

Comment: After seeing your table and number of records you have, NOT IN query might perform faster in your case, since it will operate on the smallest table, companies.